# Template typedef for std container (without specialization)?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, template-specialization, specialization

Is it possible to use typedef on a std container without specializing it?

Code like this works:

```
typedef std::vector<int> intVector;
```

But for this code:

```
template <typename T>
typedef std::vector<T> DynamicArray<T>;
```

I get an error:

> template declaration of 'typedef'

It is possible to do this in C++??

Comment: Considering that all you're basically doing is renaming `std::vector`, how untasteful would it be to use `#define DynamicArray std::vector`?

Comment: @suszterpatt - true, but I try to keep it modern and avoid usage of the unsafe macros :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, in C++11.

```
template <typename T>
using DynamicArray = std::vector<T>;
```

(Not that you should use this exact alias.)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working in Visual Studio 2010 SP1. I get "unrecognisable template declaration/definition"
I suppose it is not supported by MS yet?

Comment: @ddriver: No, it's not. And not by VC11, either, AFAIR. If you want C++11, use GCC or Clang.

Comment: I found a workaround for VS by simply inheriting vector. Please see the answer I added and shed some light if this is not a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If your compiler support c++11:

```
template <typename T>
using DynamicArray = std::vector<T>;
```

otherwise (c++98 or older) you can use a help structure like the following

```
template<typename T>
struct DynamicArray
{
  typedef std::vector<T> type;
};
```

and then use it as

```
DynamicArray<int>::type my_array;
```

Inheriting from std::vector is a possible solution but be aware that STL containers do not have virtual destructor. i.e.:

```
template <typename T>
struct DynamicArray: vector<T> { ... };

int main() {
  vector<int>* p = new DynamicArray<int>();
  delete p; // this is Undefined Behavior
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but why would I dynamically allocate a vector when it is using dynamic memory allocation for its data internally?

Comment: Also, can't I just write a destructor myself, I think the vector's destructor should be responsible for its data, I only need to take care of extra stuff I added. I might be wrong thou, I am not too good with C++.

Comment: I mean, sure, there might be problems with polymorphic usage, but since the intent is to just use the derived class I don't think there will be any problems due to the lack of virtual destructor. I mean it is not like I am going to call delete on a pointer to vector which actually points to a DynamicArray, which also has no extra dynamically allocated members to require extra care. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @ddriver You are right, if you are sure you never delete such a pointer you are good.

Comment: and if I delete from a vector pointer, what would the implications of that be if I don't have any extra members in my derived class?

Comment: It is undefined behavior as per the standard, so the implications depend on your compiler/platform/... . It might work, but unfortunately it may also delete nothing ...

Comment: Probably better if add which way is recommended? By 'using ' or by 'struct'..

Comment: @Michael `using` is the recommended way. The other is for when your compiler does not support c++11

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is invalid in C++, there is no feature like a "template typedef".

```
template <typename T>
typedef std::vector<T> DynamicArray<T>;
```

However, C++11 introduces a template alias syntax that is almost like this:

```
template <typename T>
using DynamicArray =  std::vector<T>;
```

In C++03 you can use a template metafunction like:

```
template<class T>
struct DynamicArray
{
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The common solution (if you're not using C++ 11) is to do this:

```
template<class T>
struct DynamicArray
{
    typedef std::vector<T> Type;
};
```

And use it as `DynamicArray<Something>::Type`.